# How to stop print lines?

Tags: python, printing, save, load, line

So, my code is:

```
file = open("save_file.txt")

for each_line in file:
    s = {}
    (s['name'], s['race'], s['class'], s['FOR'], s['INT'], s['DES']) = each_line.split(";")
    print(s['name'])
    print(s['race'])
    print(s['class'])
    print(s['FOR'])
    print(s['INT'])
    print(s['DES'])
file.close()
```

The `save_file.txt`:

```
Nome: d;Raça: Humano;Classe: Mago;FOR: 5;INT: 7;DES: 5
Nome: g;Raça: umano;Classe: Mo;FOR: 56;INT: 47;DES: 85
```

I want that the program print only the first line, but I don't want to delete the second line. This is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deciding not to print is very different than deleting.  You could do something like:

```
with open("save_file.txt") as f:
    for each_line in f:
        s = {}
        (s['name'], s['race'], s['class'], s['FOR'], s['INT'], s['DES']) = each_line.split(";")
        print(s['name'])
        print(s['race'])
        print(s['class'])
        print(s['FOR'])
        print(s['INT'])
        print(s['DES'])
        break  #<---
```

It breaks out of the for loop when `break` is encountered and it'd just print a single line from the file.

Also, this uses the `with` context manager to avoid having to explicitly close the file later.

---

**Edit**

```
# Read all lines into lines list, each element is a dictionary
lines = []
with open("save_file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        s = {}
        (s['name'], s['race'], s['class'], s['FOR'], s['INT'], s['DES']) = line.split(";")
        lines.append(s)

# Print first line
s = lines[0]
print(s['name'])
print(s['race'])
print(s['class'])
print(s['FOR'])
print(s['INT'])
print(s['DES'])

# Print second line
s = lines[1]
print(s['name'])
print(s['race'])
print(s['class'])
print(s['FOR'])
print(s['INT'])
print(s['DES'])

# Or with a Function
def print_line(lines, num):
    s = lines[num]
    print(s['name'])
    print(s['race'])
    print(s['class'])
    print(s['FOR'])
    print(s['INT'])
    print(s['DES'])

# Print third line
print_line(lines, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, there is a way to print only the second line?

Comment: See my edit for a way to read all the lines in at once, then print whatever line or lines you want at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

break the loop after first iteration that's all...

```
for each_line in file:
    s = {}
    (s['name'], s['race'], s['class'], s['FOR'], s['INT'], s['DES']) = each_line.split(";")
    print(s['name'])
    print(s['race'])
    print(s['class'])
    print(s['FOR'])
    print(s['INT'])
    print(s['DES'])
    break
```

Comment: Thanks, there is a way to print only the second line?

Comment: yes. Use a number..increment it in the loop...and apply check above all print..if (number==2) print..so it will print when there will be second row

Comment: @MatracadePlantão: but what you are try to do?